# Django All-Auth Facebook Integration

Tags: django-allauth

I am having problems setting up the Facebook social integration for Django All-Auth. I have successfully setup the Google login, so I am at a loss as to why one works and the other doesn't. I think it might be due to my Facebook configuration in settings.py, as Facebook has many possible options.

**Events Summary:**

- Click Login by Facebook Button on my website
- Browser redirects to Facebook website for login, and facebook requests password.
- Facebook accepts the password
- Browser redirects back to my website but gives the following error: "Social Network Login Failure, An error occurred while attempting to login via your social network account."
- Login failed

Any idea how I can diagnose what exactly is causing the problem?

**Example webhost message:**

```
[16/Nov/2016 02:14:37] "GET /accounts/facebook/login/callback/?code=AQArXlYq-4K8
UBnuACFQZK39HvVAkZzYpnkP4hI223Y5kA1JmmjdF5yOeVHnrDRpxMOPFNviDzYeSSBvWccALZHGTl-8
7_A1-jtwpDF0UdgoGSVVd9KsrGrQDrHi0i6X9l_pO76-_Ro0N8ePr4L7uUd2G3aWAlZVtAKNNPG1kNBf
OIwhb_RFRJrFvdLA5TlUXaGFdkEsRdMawyG8tdAstXdm5FcxKBRYMOE98j3yalHm5oLLeXOMKJ14EdDw
8-DHU6f5Ze1DWaWWUd-3MFP-NvF2sG4XbA6n5McPrLgYZKb_YG8Slqgo5GDVrKHT1tNedzgceCjjDXT3
TfbzZc9e-aQT9EycKAdGDr1TkKw9lO-Lqw&state=5WqSSFEKy5bc HTTP/1.1" 200 8243
```

**Example URL after return from Facebook:**

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/facebook/login/callback/?code=AQArXlYq-4K8UBnuACFQZK39HvVAkZzYpnkP4hI223Y5kA1JmmjdF5yOeVHnrDRpxMOPFNviDzYeSSBvWccALZHGTl-87_A1-jtwpDF0UdgoGSVVd9KsrGrQDrHi0i6X9l_pO76-_Ro0N8ePr4L7uUd2G3aWAlZVtAKNNPG1kNBfOIwhb_RFRJrFvdLA5TlUXaGFdkEsRdMawyG8tdAstXdm5FcxKBRYMOE98j3yalHm5oLLeXOMKJ14EdDw8-DHU6f5Ze1DWaWWUd-3MFP-NvF2sG4XbA6n5McPrLgYZKb_YG8Slqgo5GDVrKHT1tNedzgceCjjDXT3TfbzZc9e-aQT9EycKAdGDr1TkKw9lO-Lqw&state=5WqSSFEKy5bc#_=_
```

**Facebook Valid OAuth redirect URI:**

- http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/facebook/login/callback/

**Facebook Settings:**

- Client OAuth Login - Enabled
- Web OAuth Login - Enabled
- Embedded Browser OAuth Login - Enabled

**Admin Settings:**

- Client ID, Secret ID input
- Site 1 set as localhost

**Settings.py Apps:**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'home',

    # Django Standard Apps
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    # Django Crispy forms
    'crispy_forms',

    # Django allauth
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google',
]
```

**Settings.py Social:**

```
SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = \
    {
    'facebook':
    {'METHOD': 'oauth2',
    'SCOPE': ['email', 'public_profile'],
    'AUTH_PARAMS': {'auth_type': 'reauthenticate'},
    #'FIELDS': [
    #'id',
    #'email',
    #'name',
    #'first_name',
    #'last_name',
    #'verified',
    #'locale',
    #'timezone',
    #'link',
    #'gender',
    #'updated_time'],
    'EXCHANGE_TOKEN': True,
    #'LOCALE_FUNC': 'path.to.callable',
    'VERIFIED_EMAIL': False,
    'VERSION': 'v2.4'},

    'google':
    { 'SCOPE': ['profile', 'email'],
    'AUTH_PARAMS': { 'access_type': 'online' } }
    }
```

I uploaded this configuration with different redirect URIs to a test server with SSL and still have the same problem. Any ideas how I can fix this?

I am running Python 3.5.2, and the latest pip install for all-auth.

Thanks
Stephen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was just fighting this for a while.

The trick for me was that the Django-allauth "client" code needs to be the Facebook "appid", *not* the Facebook "client".

When I changed the Facebook "client" to the appid using the Django admin area (or you could edit the database), problem solved.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I remade the facebook app and input the settings and it has suddenly started working.