# Django-allauth facebook callback (/accounts/facebook/login/callback/) error without trace

Tags: django, django-allauth

I have successfully login to facebook:

```
"GET /accounts/facebook/login/ HTTP/1.0" 302 0

"GET /accounts/facebook/login/callback/?code=AQCMYR8By_NW2ArWZ63Kq00twt4mSUiQ9BBApbvwt7eLWYyiMxYJkOXuRlbXzb9tq4lS-QunyFUlKxgVc0P6D3K-rl6AVkuMUZ2o7XjJi1LNmiaiUdzT6WHzWhyAbRm2SLIkm6mwgOPMI_g47h_yRE4tra1qLMZikfWq9npXC2QWybHQ9XeaFv3zS13EqaG8H9rJ-RMKmZXb9Ti4uSzK3-Vlzk1ORLWEIbIZw3YiEpqg18fSf4hb3PEB-ro7C5FmflEdoxwaig3Vdmddvl9wOyqmx1czE4bIwqtYR3yFilZ2h0o8uEj0g03rbBY5e5GGAcNyjFmgQj1zGsgMJIQDjFXO&state=fBRf1vERs3PD HTTP/1.0" 200 4362
```

In front I recieves message

```
Social Network Login Failure
An error occurred while attempting to login via your social network account.
```

VK auth is working.

What can be wrong and now to debug it?

Any SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS and any other VIRABLES values.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the same URL you entered as callback URL in Facebook? http://localhost:8000 and http:127.0.0.1:8000 are different URLs. Registering http:127.0.0.1:8000 as callback URL in Facebook app and using localhost in browsing will result in such an error

Comment: No. I do not use localhost and port. Similar auth with similar URL for VK works.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40624344/django-all-auth-facebook-integration.
The callback is successful as it returned 200..so that means there is an issue in your configuration.

Comment: I do not understand what are they talking about. :(

Comment: Try debugging what exactly is the error. Refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36728887/debugging-django-allauth-social-network-login-failure

Comment: Tats helped somehow. Now I have an error. It about domen thad do not includes to domens list.
Facebook auth totally suxx.

Comment: Can you paste the exact error, the domain you registered on your facebook app and the domain that you are using for testing?